# filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=1,opacity=80 ) not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

> filter:
>   progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=1,opacity=80
>   )
>                                                                           opacity: 0.5; -moz-opacity: 0.5;

not working in firefox. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you forgot a ; after the ).

And opacity should be 0.8 to match 80 in the first rule.

Comment: thanx.You are right filtering has been applied but the style=1 not working

Comment: I want to aplly style for the element which has been applied filter property.filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=1,opacity=80 ) not working. only  -moz-opacity: 0.5; is working